# How to unbind a scroll event added to the window only using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have added a scroll event to the window using the below code.

```
window.onscroll=function () {
```

How to unbind this scroll event added to the window only by using Javascript?

Comment: With `window.onscroll = function(){}`?

Comment: @Sareesh you should accept the answer of AdamJB

Answer (score 5):

The answer from VRFP is slightly incorrect. The event listeners should be added and removed with `'scroll'` as the event as follows:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', myFunction, false);

window.removeEventListener('scroll', myFunction, false);
```

also, the function can be either an expression or declaration, it doesn't matter. Just be aware of function hoisting.

Function expression:

```
var myFunction = function() {
   /* do something here */
};
```

Function declaration:

```
function myFunction() {
   /* do something here */
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
var myFunction = function (event) {
   /* do something here */
};

window.addEventListener('onscroll', myFunction, false )

window.removeEventListener('onscroll', myFunction, false)
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener